# RxJava 2 Observable zip and Retrofit

Tags: android

I am using RxJava 2 and retrofit library and wanted to execute more than 700 queries where each query is a retrofit API Call.

How can I achieve this in RXJava 2 using zip operator?

Comment: 700 api calls. I would suggest changing your idea. do have a look at this sample https://github.com/ragdroid/rxify

Answer (score 0):

700 or 1000 million it does not matter, you normally has a CPU with 8 cores so only 8 process in parallel it will be executed.

You could use flatMap with MaxConcurrent

```
/**
 * FlatMap operator allow you to specify the max number of concurrent operation that this operator can process.
 * This is another way to make back pressure if you know your system cannot process more than specific number
 * of elements in the pipeline.
 */
@Test
public void asyncFlatMapWithMaxConcurrent() {
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))//Your number of request
            .flatMap(value -> Observable.just(value)
                            .map(number -> {
                                 System.out.println("Make your request here");

                                return number;
                            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    , 8)//Max concurrent operations
            .subscribe();
    new TestSubscriber()
            .awaitTerminalEvent(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

You can see more examples regarding RxJava here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will check the solution. Just asking , why there is @Test Override for this?

Comment: is a JUnit test